# Possible Permanent Join

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to check to see if the file name (Radiology_PaidClaimAudit_Member_Count_20240129.txt) in #temp2 is like one of the file names in the Insertinto lines in the code below. It works great on the "dm_Caresrc" schema, because it is only returning the 2 that are missing [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LAU8q.png)

When I try to change the schema, and modify the file masks in the code, it is not retuning any results, even when there are files in the #temp2 table.  The If statement was because I kept getting an error when #temp2 was empty, which will happen often.

I think that my join table may be permanent, and that's why it won't update with the new values
Please help

```
declare @monitor_day as int
declare @expected_file_mask as VARCHAR(80)
DECLARE @source_extract varchar(8)
DECLARE @target_extract varchar(8)
set @monitor_day = '1' ---INPUT Expected Day of receipt

SELECT  [sourcefile],
        [start_time],
        [target_table],
        DAY(start_time) as dayofmonth
        --substring(right(sourcefile,15),1,19) as source_extract,
        --substring(right(target_table,6),1,6) as target_extract
FROM [dm_Caresrc].[dbo].[TablesProcessed] with (nolock)
where DAY(start_time) <= @monitor_day-32

 CREATE TABLE #temp (
       Missing_File_mask varchar(255)
 );

INSERT INTO #temp (Missing_File_mask) VALUES ('Radiology_PaidClaimAudit_PaidClaim');
INSERT INTO #temp (Missing_File_mask) VALUES ('Radiology_PaidClaimAudit_Member');
INSERT INTO #temp (Missing_File_mask) VALUES ('Radiology_PaidClaimAudit_Provider');

CREATE TABLE #temp2 (
       sourcefile1 varchar(255)
 );

 INSERT INTO #temp2 (sourcefile1)
   select sourcefile
   FROM [dm_Caresrc].[dbo].[TablesProcessed] with (nolock)

 if (select count(*) from #temp2) > 0
 begin
   Select distinct(Missing_File_mask) 
   from #temp a 
   Inner Join #temp2 b on B.sourcefile1 not like (A.Missing_File_mask+ '%')
 end
 else
 begin
    Select distinct(Missing_File_mask) from #temp
 end

 Drop table #temp
 Drop table #temp2
```

I modified the code, and it only works for the specified schema

Answer (score 1):

I had a difficult time understanding your problem description, but looking at the code I *might* partly understand what you are trying to do.

Instead of selecting "masks where any source file does not match", I think you need to select "masks where no source file matches".

This would list any or all of the *expected* "PaidClaim", "Member", or "Provider" file categories that are *missing* from the source file list.

Try:

```
SELECT T.Missing_File_mask
FROM #temp T -- Expected
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM #temp2 T2  -- Received
    WHERE T2.sourcefile1 like (T.Missing_File_mask + '%')
)
```

There is no need to wrap the above in a `if (select count(*) from #temp2) > 0` block. If `#temp2` is empty, all of the masks will be included in the results.

If that is not it, I think you need to add more sample data (insert fixed data into #temp2) and expected results.